# angularjs: regexp fails onblur

Tags: regex, angularjs, input, trim, onblur

I'd love to detect where a string matches a regexp but this seems to fail on blur. Please see this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1BmNzij6JAf3Yqu5rdza?p=preview).

Here's the js:

```
 var endsWithPipeOrSpace = /\s+$|\|$/g;

$scope.inputGetFocus = function() {
  $scope.msg = "input gained focus"
  if (endsWithPipeOrSpace.test($scope.newquery)) {
    $scope.msg += " string match";
  } else {
    $scope.msg += " string doesn't match";
  }
}

$scope.inputLostFocus = function() {
  $scope.msg = "input has lost focus"
  if (endsWithPipeOrSpace.test($scope.newquery)) {
    $scope.msg += " string match";
  } else {
    $scope.msg += " string doesn't match";
  }
}


$scope.newQueryModified = function() {
  $scope.msg = "input modified"
  if (endsWithPipeOrSpace.test($scope.newquery)) {
    $scope.msg += " string match";
  } else {
    $scope.msg += " string doesn't match";
  }
}
```

and here's the HTML:
Please note I'm declaring ng-trim="false"

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="newquery" ng-model="newquery" 
placeholder="Enter your query" 
autofocus required autocomplete="off" 
ng-change="newQueryModified()" 
ng-trim="false" 
ng-focus="inputGetFocus()" 
ng-blur="inputLostFocus()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regexp fails on blur because the lastIndex of `endsWithPipeOrSpace` has been changed in `newQueryModified` function.

Read a bit about `RegExp` lastIndex property.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex

`The lastIndex is a read/write integer property of regular expressions that specifies the index at which to start the next match.`

When a successfull match happens for regular expression, lastIndex value is changed to length of matched string.
So here you have to reset the `lastIndex` value to 0 to test `$scope.newquery` with `endsWithPipeOrSpace` like this

```
$scope.inputLostFocus = function() {
   $scope.msg = "input has lost focus"
   endsWithPipeOrSpace.lastIndex = 0;          // reset lastIndex here
   if (endsWithPipeOrSpace.test($scope.newquery)) {
       $scope.msg += " string match";
   } else {
       $scope.msg += " string doesn't match";
   }
}
```